# Creating a File that the Path does not exists?

Tags: c#, file, path

I just can't get around this. I am able to create a file with `File.Create`... `File.CreateText` and so on but only if the path exists. If the path doesn't exist the file won't be written and returns an error.

How can I create the path?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create multiple directories from a single full path in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2134392/how-to-create-multiple-directories-from-a-single-full-path-in-c)

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Try

```
Directory.CreateDirectory(@"C:\MyApp\MySubDir\Data")
```

http://www.devx.com/vb2themax/Tip/18678

Comment: As this post mostlikely solves your problem here the additional MSDN information: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/as2f1fez.aspx

Comment: And how do we check if the path exists? or we just call this function.

Comment: READ! MSDN Says: If the folder already exists,  CreateDirectory does nothing.

Answer (score 23):

Given that you've the full path (Folder + File name), the following code will ensure your required directory path exists (if it does not exist already)

```
        FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(fileFullPath);

        if (!fileInfo.Exists)
            Directory.CreateDirectory(fileInfo.Directory.FullName);


        //create the file ...
```

Answer (score 7):

below should also work

```
    FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(fileFullPath);
    if (!fileInfo.Directory.Exists) fileInfo.Directory.Create()
```

work on directory of fileinfo, rather than static directory class

Answer (score 5):

You will need to create the Directory first. It will create all of the subdirectories that don't exist within the path you send it. It's quite a powerful piece of functionality.

```
Directory.CreateDirectory(filePath);
```

If you don't know whether the directory exists or not you can use Directory.Exists. But not for this case as it would be pointless. MSDN states that CreateDirectory does nothing if the directory currently exists. But if you wanted to check existance of the directory for another reason you can use:

```
  if(Directory.Exists(folder) == false)
    {
    //do stuff  
    }
```

Comment: This won't work if the filePath is a full path (folder + file name) - it'll annoyingly create a directory with the name of your desired file (eg if filePath is `pathTo\helloWorld.txt` it'll create a folder named `helloWorld.txt` inside the folder `pathTo`).

Comment: @DanielElkington are you sure about that?

Comment: I tested this the other day and that’s what happened. Ashraf Alam’s answer using the FileInfo class to split out the directory name worked. But if you know the path is only a directory then this will work.

Answer (score 2):

```
Directory.CreateDirectory("path");
```