# How to create multiple directories from a single full path in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, base-class-library

If you have a full path like: `"C:\dir0\dir1\dir2\dir3\dir4\"` how would you best implement it so that all directories are present?

Is there a method for this in the BCL? If not, what's the most elegant way to do this?

Answer (score 415, accepted):

I would call `Directory.CreateDirectory(@"C:\dir0\dir1\dir2\dir3\dir4\")`.

Contrary to popular belief, [`Directory.CreateDirectory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/54a0at6s.aspx) will automatically create whichever parent directories do not exist.
 In MSDN's words, `Creates all directories and subdirectories as specified by path.`

If the entire path already exists, it will do nothing.  (It won't throw an exception)

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know this. The path has to be a directory path, not a file path, right?

Comment: @Joan:Yes; you can call `Path.GetDirectoryName` to get it.

Comment: It should have called CreateDirectoryTree

Comment: thx, works with `DirectoryInfo.Create()` also

Comment: @OldSchool, agree, CreateDirectoryTree would be a great name. Though I prefer to have a rare gem named incorrectly than not having the gem ;) This functionality is very, very useful and unique among frameworks.

Answer (score 3):

Create directories from complete filepath

```
private String EvaluatePath(String path){

    try
    {
        String folder = Path.GetDirectoryName(path);
        if (!Directory.Exists(folder))
        {
            // Try to create the directory.
            DirectoryInfo di = Directory.CreateDirectory(folder);
        }
    }
    catch (IOException ioex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ioex.Message);
        return "";
    }
    return path;
}
```