# How to create new file with path?

Tags: c#

Let's say I need to create a new file whose path is ".\a\bb\file.txt". The folder a and bb may not exist. How can I create this file in C# in which folder a and bb are automatically created if not exist?

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2134392/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This will create the file along with the folders a and bb if they do not exist

```
FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(@".\a\bb\file.txt");
DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(@".\a\bb");
if(!di.Exists)
{
    di.Create();
}

if (!fi.Exists) 
{
    fi.Create().Dispose();
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Try this:

```
string file = @".\aa\b\file.txt";
Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.GetDirectoryName(file));
using (var stream = File.CreateText(file))
{
    stream.WriteLine("Test");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
new DirectoryInfo(Path.GetDirectoryName(fileName)).Create();
```

Comment: You miss file creation, after folder creation