# How I can Save Picture as file path from window phone 7 to server

Tags: image, windows-phone-7, save-as

I have application which is selecting image from image gallery and I have a image path for e.g
PhotoResult e e.OriginalFileName I am getting complete path so how I can directly saveAs this image to the Server using Windows Phone.

I have all the stream and path so how I can save this image into the my server as a Image just like the folder system and inside the folder I have Imagename.jpg so how I can save even I don't have a `Server.Map()` into the Windows Phone. Is there any utility or any code where I can upload image?

It like how I can Map this image to server like Server.Map('`');

Comment: duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6373702/save-image-into-isolated-storage

Comment: @DerekBeattie it is not duplicate my Question is I have all the stream and path so how I can save this image into the my server as a Image just like the folder system and inside the folder I have Imagename.jpg so how I can save even I don't have a Server.Map() into the windows Phone. so is there any utility or any code where I can upload image.

Comment: Sorry, I misread.  You might look at restsharp for uploading images.

Answer (score 0):

You can send the image to server and use Directory.CreateDirectory in c#.

Help link:- [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2779628/how-to-create-new-file-with-path]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2779628/how-to-create-new-file-with-path) in the server which will create the path for you.

Then you have to save the file to that path. The link provided by Dererk will allow you to store image to Isolated Storage in WP7.