# How to create multiple directories from a single full path?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Sorry to ask this again,
[I have already seen this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2134392/how-to-create-multiple-directories-from-a-single-full-path-in-c).

I am using the following code to create multiple directories from a single full path, but it isn't doing anything. My compiler enters the conditions and runs the command, but doesn't create directory. I don't know what is wrong.

```
if (!Directory.Exists(@"~/Documents/2/images/"))
{
    Directory.CreateDirectory(@"~/Documents/2/images/");
}
```

Comment: This is probably creating a directory called `~` as a subdirectory of the current directory. Is that not what you're expecting it to do?

Comment: oh no sorry, i am building in asp.net web application and ~ is the root directory of my solution

Comment: You might believe that `~` is the "root directory of your solution", but the `Directory.CreateDirectory()` function has no such opinion.

Comment: but i gives me the actual path which is in c:\ drive

Comment: Look into [`HttpServerUtility.MapPath`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.mappath.aspx)

Comment: You don't have to do the check, if the directory already exists `CreateDirectory` doesn't do anything.

Comment: Try it with full path... like Directory.CreateDirectory(@"C:/abc/doc/2/images/")

If you are still not able to create the directory then probably the reason could be is, your *User* is not having *write* rights on that particular drive/directory. So try with changing the directory. Let's say try it with D:/abc/def etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here seems to be a missconception with the tilde "~" symbol, in ASP.NET applications the tilde is frequently used to designate the application root directory **but it doesn't work everywhere**, in fact, the "~" symbol only works on URLs so `@"~/Documents/2/images/"` is not a path, it's a URL that represents something like http://myserver.com/MyApplicationRoot/Documents/2/images/

To use the "~" in this context you must map the URL to a physical path, you can do so with `Server.MapPath(@"~/Documents/2/images/")`, which will return something like `"c:\inetpub\wwwroot\myApp\Documents\2\images\"`, and that's what you should pass on to `CreateDirectory`

A "~" when passed to a physical path will be interpreted literally and will refer to a folder named "~"

Answer (score 0):

```
> // Returns a boolean for sucess or insucess. The path is splitted using strtok.

int mkdir_rec(char *p_path)
{
    char full_path[1024]="";
    char *path = strdup(p_path);
    char *dir = strtok(path, "/");
    struct stat st;

    while (dir!=NULL)
    {
      if (strcmp(full_path,"")!=0) 
        strcat(full_path, "/");
      strcat(full_path, dir);
      int status = stat(full_path, &st);

      if (status == -1) // diretory do not exist
        if (mkdir(full_path, 0700)!=0)
          return 0;
      dir = strtok(NULL, "/");  // next subdirectory
    }

    free(path);
    return 1;
}
```